# jquery conflict between two scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

I have a conflict problem between 2 jqueries that I use, I've checked the jQuery.noConflict() thingy but since I'm a bit of a rookie into it i don't know what to do with it, so if you can give me a hand that'd be great.

It seems that "jquery-2.1.4.min.js" makes "jquery-ui-1.8rc1.custom.min.js" to stop working, so instead of receiving the pop-up windows nothing happens.

Thanks in advance.

The code:

```
<script src="/myjs/js/jquery-ui-1.8rc1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () {

        var mensaje = "<%= mensaje%>";
        var $dialogDel = $('<div></div>')
        .html(mensaje)
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Alert',
            buttons: { "Ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } }  
        });
        if(mensaje != ""){
            $dialogDel.dialog('open');
        }
    }); 

    function add(){

        var archivo = document.adddoc.add_archivo.value;

        extensiones_permitidas = new Array(".htm", ".html", ".txt", ".doc",".xls",".zip",".pdf",".jpg",".rar",".docx",".xlsx"); 


        extension = (archivo.substring(archivo.lastIndexOf("."))).toLowerCase(); 

        permitida = false; 
        for (var i = 0; i < extensiones_permitidas.length; i++) { 
           if (extensiones_permitidas[i] == extension) { 
           permitida = true; 
           break; 
           } 
        } 
        if (!permitida) { 
            alert("The extension is not correct");
        }else{
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .html('Doc beeing uploaded, please wait.')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'Alert'
            });
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            $('#adddoc').submit();
        }

    }

</script>

    <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/myjs/js/jquery.ezdz.min.js"></script>
   <script>

        $('[type="file"]').ezdz({
            text: 'drop a file',
            validators: {
                maxWidth:  100,
                maxHeight: 200
            }/* ,
            reject: function(file, errors) {
                if (errors.mimeType) {
                    alert(file.name + ' must be an image.');
                }

                if (errors.maxWidth) {
                    alert(file.name + ' must be width:600px max.');
                }

                if (errors.maxHeight) {
                    alert(file.name + ' must be height:400px max.');
                }
            } */
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried including jQuery before jQuery UI?

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle ? We will see if only you have this problem.

Comment: @user3272243 Ok. Have you considered using a more up to date version of jQuery UI since you're using the latest (I think?) version of jQuery itself

Comment: @JamesThorpe actually.... if i change the order jquery-2.1.4.min.js is the one to stop working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`jquery-ui-1.8rc1` is shipped with `jquery-1.4.1.js`](http://jqueryui.com/download/all/).

Since you are using a way newer version of jQuery, it could be compatibility problems.

Do you perhaps get any warnings or errors in the console? Perhaps it has something to do with [deprecated functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/).

Comment: Yes, when i click on the button that should open the pop-up i get: TypeError: $(...).html(...).dialog is not a function

Comment: you used jquery-ui-1.8rc1.custom.min.js. I assume this was a version in which you selected only some functionality. Dialog was probably not included.